# Nodejs detached child process killed when parent process is killed

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I'm on linux and I use a node process to spawn a child process which runs a bash script. The bash script does a dist-upgrade. Doing the dist-upgrade kills node, which kills the parent process, but also the upgrade itself.

According to the nodejs docs a child process can keep running if the parent process exits, if the child process has been spawned with the `detached` flag.

If I run this code:

```
const child_process = require("child_process");
child_process.spawn('xterm', [], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore','ignore','ignore']
}).unref();
```

And when I kill the parent process in webstorm, the child process (xterm window) also exits... When I kill the parent using `kill -9/15/...` the child process keeps running. So it seems that some ways can still kill the child process if detached. But I don't know exactly when or why and how to avoid it?

Comment: When testing the snippet you provide, I can open a Firefox window (on OSX) and keep it running after the process exits (exits immediatly when `unref()` is called on the spawned process). If I don't call `unref()`, node stays in a waiting state, but when I kill it, Firefox stays open. If I don't provide the `detached` flag, then when I kill the process, Firefox exits too. Therefore, I think there is something external to the code you provided which makes it not work as expected, because this code works well on my end ... What is the broader context here?

Comment: @SamuelBolduc Yeah, I did some further experimentation and the child process indeed keeps running if I kill the parent process using `kill -9/2/1/15 pid` or `killall nodejs`. However, I first ran it from webstorm and when I stop running the process in webstorm, the child process still quits. So I guess depending on the way you kill the process the child process will stay alive or quit, but I don't know exactly when.

I've added more info in the OP.

Comment: I met the same behavior with WebStorm. Stopping debug session killed the detached child process. But very rare it does not kill the child process. @SebaKerckhof, have you any progress on this ?

Comment: The problem is still here Node 10.15.0 WebStorm 2018.3.